# Why is there a difference between do(lm...) and geom_smooth(method="lm")?

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting

I have an external calibration curve that slightly goes into saturation. So I fit a polynomial of second order, and a dataframe of measured samples, of which I'd like to know the concentration.

```
df_calibration=structure(list(dilution = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 
0.8, 0.9, 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1), 
    area = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 7800, 
    8200, 8500, 1200, 2200, 3200, 4200, 5200, 6200, 7200, 8000, 
    8400, 8700), substance = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
    "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

df_samples=structure(list(area = c(1100, 1800, 2500, 3200, 3900, 1300, 2000, 
2700, 3400, 4100), substance = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

To calculate now the actual dilutions from measured samples, I take the parameters generated from this fit:

```
df_fits=df_calibration %>% group_by(substance) %>% 
  do(fit = lm(area ~ poly(dilution,2), data = .))%>%
  tidy(fit) %>% 
  select(substance, term, estimate) %>% 
  spread(term, estimate)

df_fits=df_fits %>% rename(a=`poly(dilution, 2)2`,b=`poly(dilution, 2)1`,c=`(Intercept)`)

#join parameters with sample data
df_samples=left_join(df_samples,df_fits)
```

and this formula [image: formula to calculate]

```
#calculate with general solution for polynomial 2nd order
df_samples$dilution_calc=
  (df_samples$b*(-1)+sqrt(df_samples$b^2-(4*df_samples$a*(df_samples$c-df_samples$area))))/(2*df_samples$a)
```

However, when I plot this now, I notice something very odd.
The calculated x-values (dilutions) do not end up on the curve from `stat_smooth()`. The additional dotted line is put with the parameters from the equation in the graph (that match the numbers in the data frame) for substance "A". So my calculations should be correct (or not?) Why is there a difference? What am I doing wrong? How could I get parameters from the fit done by `stat_smooth()`?

```
my.formula=y ~ poly(x,2)
ggplot(df_calibration, aes(x = dilution, y = area)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE, formula = my.formula) +

  stat_function(fun=function(x){5250+(7980*x)+(-905*x^2)},      
              inherit.aes = F,linetype="dotted")+

  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, 
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "~~~")), 
               parse = TRUE) +         
  geom_point(shape=17)+
  geom_point(data=df_samples,
           aes(x=dilution_calc,y=area),
           shape=1,color="red")+
  facet_wrap(~substance,scales = "free")
```

[image: plot with odd behaviour]

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm unable figure out what the "quardatic formula" has to do with predictions from a second order polynomial. So you should probably describe in more detail what logic you are using. If you are using the coefficients from `poly()`, then you a) need to include the intercept and b) need to remember that the second order term has been made orthogonal to the first order term. AND, despite executing `library(tidyverse)` I'm still getting "Error in tidy(., fit) : could not find function "tidy""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `poly` computes orthogonal polynomials. You can turn orthogonalization off with the `raw=TRUE` argument.

Note that the formula makes two appearances: once with the original variable names in fitting the regressions and then in `stat_smooth` using the generic variable names `x` and `y`. But otherwise it should be the same formula, with `raw=TRUE`.

```r
library("tidyverse")

# Define/import your data here....

df_fits <- df_calibration %>%
  group_by(substance) %>%
  do(fit = lm(area ~ poly(dilution, 2, raw = TRUE), data = .)) %>%
  broom::tidy(fit) %>%
  select(substance, term, estimate) %>%
  spread(term, estimate) %>%
  # It is simpler to rename the coefficients here
  setNames(c("substance", "c", "b", "a"))

# join parameters with sample data
df_samples <- left_join(df_samples, df_fits)

# calculate with general solution for polynomial 2nd order
df_samples <- df_samples %>%
  mutate(dilution_calc = (b * (-1) + sqrt(b^2 - (4 * a * (c - area)))) / (2 * a))

my.formula <- y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)

df_calibration %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = dilution, y = area)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, formula = my.formula) +
  geom_point(shape = 17) +
  geom_point(
    data = df_samples,
    aes(x = dilution_calc, y = area),
    shape = 1, color = "red"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~substance, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>